# Referencing ASPX controls from an External JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a question. I have a aspx control (for e.g textbox). I reference it using document.getElementById('<%=textbox.ClientID%>').value. When I have the code in the same aspx file it works. But as soon reference it from an external file (example MyJSFunctions.js), I cannnot. I get an error saying "the object does not exist or it is null"

I have included the name of the js file like

I did this because I like having all my js functions in a seperate file nad doing this also reduces the load overhead.

Why is this happening? Can I accomplish the same using jquery?

Answer (score 4):

You will need to parametise your Javascript to accept the desired argument, then pass the inline ASP.NET script *within the server-side page or control* as the value of such. This will allow the engine to render the inline code appropriately.

It happens because the server renders your pages (not in the sense of a browser rendering HTML, but rather the ASP.NET engine making transformations to turn your .NETified web mark-up into standard web mark-up) prior to pushing them down to the client - this will only happen for "registered" types, and that doesn't (and shouldn't) include Javascript files (although you *can* technically register items to handle, unless you have a bespoke module to handle compilation of inline scripting among Javascript, then it would err anyway.)

jQuery essentially being something of a Javascript framework, you're in the same boat with that, so to speak.

As an example, consider the following...

Your script file:

```
function doSomethingJavascripty(withThisClientID) {
    //do something with...
    document.getElementById(withThisClientID).value;
}
```

Your ASPX page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/script.js"><script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    //call your function when appropriate...
    doSomethingJavascripty('<%=textbox.ClientID%>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is have the following Javascript code in your ASPX page:

```
var myTextbox = '<%=textbox.ClientID%>';
```

Then, in your external JS file (make sure this is *after* the above line), have:

```
document.getElementById(myTextbox).value
```

Another alternative is just hardcode in the ClientID into your code, but note you'll break it if you change the ID or parent container of that textbox control in the future.

Comment: The first suggestion, while possible, is a process of decoupling dependent elements, which is generally a bad idea for much the same reasons as the second suggestion; the second suggestion, well, that's just a plain ol' terrible idea.

Comment: Mr, I'd love to understand your suggestion better.  What do you mean by "parametise your Javascript"?

Comment: Seriously? OK... alter the script to accept [a parameter](http://javascript.about.com/library/bltut08.htm), or "named arguments" if you prefer that terminology, as part of the function signature; then utilise the script by invoking the function and passing the appropriate argument (or value), keeping both the variable and the JS call in something of alignment; as opposed to just defining a variable _anywhere_ and calling a seemingly unrelated function, only to find out later that it is highly tied to that variable.

Comment: That would force him to move his calling code into the ASPX file (and for all we know this code is non-trivial.)  He's already pointed out he wants all his JS functions in a separate file.

Comment: The functions would be, you'd just be invoking it from the ASPX file - probably the same about of script required to define the variable as you have here, but much clearer.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment is it possible make this clear with an example?

Comment: @Mike, I did try you suggestion. Wouldn't it give me the same error when I type var myTextbox = '<%=textbox.ClientID%>';?

Comment: Nope, because that line would be in your ASPX file, not your JS file.  You can use the <%= ... %> syntax as long as you're in an ASPX file.